# cordova InAppBrowser does not work in windows 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I collect the application to Cordoba 3.5 platform Windows Phone 7-8, but I have a problem: `InAppBrowser` does not work on this platform. 
Plugin is installed correctly, because it works on other platforms.

Here are the settings in config.xml:

```
<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" /> 
<access origin="*" browserOnly="true" /> 
<feature name="InAppBrowser" />
```

JS code:

```
window.open ('google.com', '_systems');
```

When I click on the link, nothing happens. 
Help please, or tell me what either alternative can I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `window.open('http://www.google.com','_system')` not _systems